# How to open a Pdf file in IFrame?

Tags: c#

How Can (in a list with candidates) select one pdf/docx file and open it in a Iframe?
Here is an Image of how the list of candidates looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify the question. As it stands it’s not clear are you having issues with creating an iframe, setting the URL for it to display, selecting a document from the list, sending a document from the server to the browser, or some other issue.

Comment: @Dorin, download the pdf as a blob and open it, you probably want to download an npm package to handle that

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly where do you want to show that iframe, but this code will help you:

Insert a Literal into your aspx:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

And this is your C#

```
string pathFinal = "pdf/yourPDF.pdf"
string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"800px\">";
embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a></object>";
Literal1.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl(pathFinal));
```

Comment: im using asp.net core, it's using html not aspx

Comment: Ah Ok. Then try to send the string that returns from "string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl(pathFinal));" to the html.

Comment: I'm not using path when uploading or downloading the file into the db